# Python app with an API for database access

Tags: python, api, design-patterns

I am writing a micro-service that will have to share database owned by a different micro-service.

I understand that from a micro-services architecture perspective, this is not a good design. Hence, I decided to separate out the database access as another micro-service, whose only task it to manage access to db.

I need pointers on how I may write such an app using Python which exposes API for read/write to a database?

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is not a *design perspective* answer.

Did you have a chance to take a look at [sandman](https://github.com/jeffknupp/sandman), a Python library that can generate a REST API over a database?